# Estou com um problema na conexão do firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-database, firestore

Eu sou novo no firebase, estou testando como posso fazer a integração do firebase com meu codigo javascript.

Porêm estou com os seguintes erros:

- GET http://192.168.15.172:5500/firebase/app net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
- GET http://192.168.15.172:5500/firebase/firestore net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
- Error handling response: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws/ws' is invalid.
  at init (chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:22:18)
  at chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:65:13

---

ja coloquei o npm install firebase, ja tentei usar direto com as tags mas nada deu certo.
Alguem consegue me ajudar por favor? agradeço desde já

java

```
import { initializeApp } from "/firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "/firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBOKO8JBu7X5pxMjiryp4ouSN8nIWk6xOA",
    authDomain: "new-basic-a1920.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "new-basic-a1920",
    storageBucket: "new-basic-a1920.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "391188058336",
    appId: "1:391188058336:web:09bde4b4b0235ec2874085"

};
//init firebase app
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init services
const db = getFirestore();

//collection ref

const collectionRef = collection(db,'new-basic');

//get collection data
  
getDocs(collectionRef).then((snapshot)=>{
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
   
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você esqueceu de adicionar alguns scripts que precisa estar no html para o firebase funcionar. Na página do seu projeto no site do firebase e copie o script do **firebase sdk**

Comment: entendi, mas o que necessariamente eu preciso colocar no html? todo o codigo que está la para copiar eu ja coloquei no codigo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Victor Adicionei outra resposta, olha se agora com o script que mandei resolve seu problema.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta adicionar esse script, o npm install não deu certo no seu caso pois o npm  só é usado em projetos node, como no seu caso é apenas html e javascript, não seria necessário o npm install. Tenta usar esse script que peguei do site Firebase.

```
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAuYbd2C3kH0MJqUroio9owupCs9CVkyVU",
    authDomain: "colegio-644fd.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "colegio-644fd",
    storageBucket: "colegio-644fd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "505343880754",
    appId: "1:505343880754:web:efc8629e639761e67d562b",
    measurementId: "G-PX5BXEF9HK"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: eu atualizei para esse, assim com tentei varias vezes. Nao deu certo, não sei o que pode ser pq eu segui tudo que tinha sobre na documentação do firebase e nada deu certo